# Mysql functions procedures

Tags: mysql

Hey Guys I have never been to violent about mysql, 
but this time I have been wanting to do more with it. 
So I have been thinking that it would be nice to have a function that could: 
Return a record set.
Seems doable!? So that's what I did. 
Only thing is I got an error

`-->ERROR 1415 not allowed to return a result set from a function;`

:$

So I mean am I crazy to think that this not very practical unless you want to use mysql to like format text into xml.
Given that it is likely that my expectation  seems to be within the reach of mysql
Can somebody enlighten me as to correct this simple example?

```
CREATE FUNCTION func01(value1 INT )
RETURNS varchar(150)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_name VARCHAR(150);
  SET var_name = "";
  SELECT users.username
    FROM users
    WHERE Id = param1;
  RETURN var_name;
END;
```

Thank you for your help on this. Please correct it I really want a working example of a function or procedure the reference is so slim on this...
:)

Comment: Sorry guys i had to edit the code in the first minute pasted the wrong block :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func01(value1 INT )
RETURNS varchar(150)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE var_name VARCHAR(150);
 SET var_name = "";
SELECT users.username into var_name
FROM users
WHERE Id = value1;
RETURN var_name;
END;
```

Now it should works.

Saludos :)